# How to access value of collection property of Model in ClientRowTemplate of KendoUI

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc, kendo-ui

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.AirlineCode).Title("Airline");
        columns.Bound(p => p.SegmentInfo[0].FareClass).Title("Fare Class");
    }
    .ClientRowTemplate( 
        "<tr>"+
        "<td style =\"width: 130px\"><img src=\"/Content/themes/base/image/#=AirlineCode#.jpg\"/><span> #=AirlineName#</span></td>" + 
        "<td><div class=\"ClassType\"> //#=SegmentInfo[0].FareClass//#  </div></td>"+"</tr>"
    )
```

How should I write `//#=SegmentInfo[0].FareClass//#` section of could to get the value from Model Property `SegmentInfo` ,which is an class object and I need to access it's Property called `FareClass` which is string object.

Try to give the proper syntax to access this kind of object value.

Thanks in advance to my helper.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how well it will work with an array but try.

```
.ClientRowTemplate( 
        "<tr>"+
        "<td style =\"width: 130px\"><img src=\"/Content/themes/base/image/#=AirlineCode#.jpg\"/><span> #=AirlineName#</span></td>" + 
        "<td><div class=\"ClassType\"> #=SegmentInfo[0].FareClass#  </div></td>"+"</tr>"
    )
```

(Remove the // completely)